# Object are only showing as wireframe, even in solid and material preview mode

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

My objects are only showing as a wireframe, even in solid and material preview mode. No matter what mode I use, it shows a wireframe. I am not aware of changing anything in my files, I've only opened them.

Comment: hello could you please share one object of your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Have you checked if the *Display As* option (*Object Properties > Viewport Display*) for the object is set to *Wire* instead of *Textured*?

Comment: I fixed it buy uninstalling and re-installing blender for anyone else having this issue :)